# PyOpenSSL reading certificate/pkey file

Tags: x509certificate, pyopenssl

That's how i create certificate

```
  from OpenSSL import crypto

  cert = crypto.X509()
  cert.get_subject().C            = countryName
  cert.get_subject().ST           = stateOrProvinceName
  ...
```

[Here](http://www.themacaque.com/?p=1057) what generation looks like.
Now, how do I extract those values fomr certificate using PyOpenSSL backwards from plain files?

So here's what I cameup with

```
def certext(certstr):
  p1 = Popen(['printf', certstr], stdout=PIPE)
  p2 = Popen(['openssl', 'x509', '-text'], stdin=p1.stdout, stdout=PIPE)
  p1.stdout.close()
  output = p2.communicate()[0]
  return output
```

Answer (score 20):

You can load a PEM certificate as follows:

```
import OpenSSL.crypto

st_cert=open(certfile, 'rt').read()

c=OpenSSL.crypto
cert=c.load_certificate(c.FILETYPE_PEM, st_cert)
```

and a private key with:

```
st_key=open(keyfile, 'rt').read()
key=c.load_privatekey(c.FILETYPE_PEM, st_key)
```

where certfile and keyfile are the filenames.

Comment: Just wanted to also add...you don't need separate files for the cert and the private key file. They can both be in the same file and read once. When loading the private key and certificate from that one file, `OpenSSL` takes care of everything. Much more convenient.